# Pyinstaller/Pyarmor IndexError

Tags: python, random, pyinstaller, pyarmor

I am making a Python script that will go through a .txt file to find live proxies ones. The program works in Python and calls for the definition 'proxies' when required so the script runs until 'proxies is called.

[image: (The Python source code)]

```
def proxies():
    proxy_file = open("proxy.txt", "r")
    proxy_text = proxy_file.readlines()
    line = random.choice(proxy_text)
    ip = line.replace("\n", "")
    if str(ip).startswith("http"):
        pass
    else:
        https = "https://"+ip
        http = "http://"+ip
    proxy = {
        "https":https,
        "http":http
    }
    return proxy
```

--

If obfuscate & pack it with pyarmor it is unable to read the file

[image]

This is the code I use to pack pyarmor: "pyarmor pack -e"--onefile" file.py"

--

Then if I try to pack it via pyinstaller I get a similar issue

[image]

This is the code I use to pack pyinstaller: pyinstaller --onefile file.py

--

If anyone knows how I could fix this issue it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: Sorry about that mate! I'm new to this so I wasn't sure how to use it! Thanks for pointing it out anyways :)